# What is the difference in heap configurations? Separation logic with CVC5 SMT solver

Tags: logic, smt-solvers

I am figuring out separation logic and trying to run simple examples in CVC5 smt solver. I am missing some core understanding of how pointers and values are treated there and I don't know where to look for more information.

I am sorry for the long snippets, but they are very simple.

### First query

```lisp
(set-logic QF_ALL)
(set-info :smt-lib-version 2.6)

(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-option :produce-proofs true)
(set-option :produce-unsat-cores true)

; heap with uninterpreted sort as Data
(declare-sort Data 0)
; "single" element for the pointers to point to
(declare-const unit Data)
; Heap declaration
(declare-heap (Int Data))

; Two pointers
(declare-const left Int)
(declare-const right Int)

; constraints for better readability of the model
(assert (= (as sep.nil Int) 0))
(assert (>= left 0))
(assert (>= right 0))

; query itself
(assert (not 
    (sep
        (pto left unit) 
        (pto right unit)  
    )
))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

#### CVC5 output

```lisp
sat
(
; cardinality of Data is 1
; rep: (as @Data_0 Data)
(define-fun unit () Data (as @Data_0 Data))
(define-fun left () Int 1)
(define-fun right () Int 2)
)
(heap
(sep (pto 2 (as @Data_0 Data)) (pto 1 (as @Data_0 Data)))
(= (as sep.nil Int) 0)
)
```

---

### Second query

```lisp
(set-logic QF_ALL)
(set-info :smt-lib-version 2.6)

(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-option :produce-proofs true)
(set-option :produce-unsat-cores true)

; heap with uninterpreted sort as Data
(declare-sort Data 0)
; "single" element for the pointers to point to
(declare-const unit Data)
; Heap declaration
(declare-heap (Int Data))

; Two pointers
(declare-const left Int)
(declare-const right Int)

; constraints for better readability of the model
(assert (= (as sep.nil Int) 0))
(assert (>= left 0))
(assert (>= right 0))

; query itself
(assert  
    (sep
        (pto left unit) 
        (pto right unit)  
    )
)

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

#### CVC5 output

```lisp
sat
(
; cardinality of Data is 1
; rep: (as @Data_0 Data)
(define-fun unit () Data (as @Data_0 Data))
(define-fun left () Int 1)
(define-fun right () Int 2)
)
(heap
(sep (pto 2 unit) (pto 1 unit))
(= (as sep.nil Int) 0)
)
```

---

## Question about the second heap

```lisp
(heap
(sep (pto 2 unit) (pto 1 unit))
(= (as sep.nil Int) 0)
)
```

Why the second heap satisfies `(sep (pto left unit) (pto right unit))`, despite both pointers pointing to the same `unit`?

## Question about the first heap

```lisp
(heap
(sep (pto 2 (as @Data_0 Data)) (pto 1 (as @Data_0 Data)))
(= (as sep.nil Int) 0)
)
```

Why is this heap satisfies `not (sep (pto left unit) (pto right unit)` even with `unit` being equal to `@Data_0`, which works for the other query?

---

Why these similar-looking heaps are satisfying mutually exclusive conditions?

I am looking to some paper or documentation page for the in-depth explanation.

Comment: Maybe try https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kai, thank you, I will try if there are no answers here

Comment: @Kai I'm not sure proofassistants is the right place to ask, as long as CVC5 and other SAT/SMT solvers are _not_ proof assistants (they are automatic theorem provers)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the question.  The model construction for the separation logic heap in cvc5 was wrong in this case.  This will be fixed by https://github.com/cvc5/cvc5/pull/9574.